# How to apply machine learning techniques / how to use model outputs

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am a plant scientist new to machine learning. I have had success writing code and following tutorials of machine learning techniques. My issue is trying to understand how to actually apply these techniques to answer real world questions. I don't really understand how to use the model outputs to answer questions.

I recently followed a tutorial creating an algorithm to detect credit card fraud. All of the models ran nicely and I understand how to build them; but, how in the world do I take this information and translate it into a definitive answer? Following the same example, lets say I wrote this code for my job how would I then take real credit card data and screen it using this algorithm? I really want to establish a link between running these models and generating a useful output from real data.

Thank you all.

In the name of being concise I will highlight some specific examples using the same data set found here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CTAlmlREFRaEN3NoHHitewpqAtWS5cVQ/view

```
# Import
creditcard_data <- read_csv('PATH')

# Restructure
creditcard_data$Amount=scale(creditcard_data$Amount)
NewData=creditcard_data[,-c(1)]
head(NewData)

#Split
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
data_sample = sample.split(NewData$Class,SplitRatio=0.80)
train_data = subset(NewData,data_sample==TRUE)
test_data = subset(NewData,data_sample==FALSE)
```

1) Decision Tree

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
decisionTree_model <- rpart(Class ~ . , creditcard_data, method = 'class')
predicted_val <- predict(decisionTree_model, creditcard_data, type = 'class')
probability <- predict(decisionTree_model, creditcard_data, type = 'prob')
rpart.plot(decisionTree_model)
```

2) Artificial Neural Network

```
library(neuralnet)
ANN_model =neuralnet (Class~.,train_data,linear.output=FALSE)
plot(ANN_model)
predANN=compute(ANN_model,test_data)
resultANN=predANN$net.result
resultANN=ifelse(resultANN>0.5,1,0)
```

3) Gradient Boosting

```
library(gbm, quietly=TRUE)

# train GBM model
system.time(
  model_gbm <- gbm(Class ~ .
                   , distribution = "bernoulli"
                   , data = rbind(train_data, test_data)
                   , n.trees = 100
                   , interaction.depth = 2
                   , n.minobsinnode = 10
                   , shrinkage = 0.01
                   , bag.fraction = 0.5
                   , train.fraction = nrow(train_data) / (nrow(train_data) + nrow(test_data))
  )
)
# best iteration
gbm.iter = gbm.perf(model_gbm, method = "test")
model.influence = relative.influence(model_gbm, n.trees = gbm.iter, sort. = TRUE)

# plot
plot(model_gbm)

# plot
gbm_test = predict(model_gbm, newdata = test_data, n.trees = gbm.iter)
gbm_auc = roc(test_data$Class, gbm_test, plot = TRUE, col = "red")
print(gbm_auc)
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, your question is really broad.And I fear interpretation of models etc comes with the data set, and we are definitely not so familiar with what you have done. Do you have an actual programming issue?

Answer (score 0):

You develop your model with, preferably, three data sets.
Training, Testing and Validation. (Sometimes different terminology is used.)
Here, Train and Test sets are used to develop the model.
The model you decide upon must never see any of the Validation set. This set is used to see how good your model is, in effect it would simulate real-world new data that may come to you in the future. Once you decide your model does perform to an acceptable level you can then go back to running all your data to produce the final operational model. Then any new 'live' data of interest is fed to the model and produces an output. In the case of the fraud detection it would output some probability: here you need human input to decide at what level you would flag the event as fraudulent enough to warrant further investigation.
At periodic intervals or as you data arrives or your model performance weakens (fraudsters may become more cunning!) you would repeat the whole process.